# Making script wait until iframe has loaded before running

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The site I'm working on has a Live Chat plugin on an iframe. I'm trying to change an image if there are no agents available. My code works on the console, but nothing on the site.

```
var LiveChatStatus = $("iframe").contents().find(".agentStatus").html();
if (LiveChatStatus =="Offline"){
    $('#liveChat').html('<img src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/product_images/theme_images/liveoffline.png">');
}
```

I tried this:

```
$('iframe').ready(function(){
    var LiveChatStatus = $("iframe").contents().find(".agentStatus").html();
    if (LiveChatStatus =="Offline"){
        $('#liveChat').html('<img src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/product_images/theme_images/liveoffline.png">');
    }
});
```

And this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var LiveChatStatus = $("iframe").contents().find(".agentStatus").html();
   if (LiveChatStatus =="Offline"){
       $('#liveChat').html('<img src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/product_images/theme_images/liveoffline.png">');
   }
});
```

But neither worked

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The best solution is to define a function in your parent such as `function iframeLoaded(){...}` and then in the iframe use:

```
$(function(){
    parent.iframeLoaded();
})
```

this works cross-browser.

If you cannot change the code within the iframe, your best solution will be to attach the `load` event to the iframe..

```
$(function(){
    $('iframe').on('load', function(){some code here...}); //attach the load event listener before adding the src of the iframe to prevent from the handler to miss the event..
    $('iframe').attr('src','http://www.iframe-source.com/'); //add iframe src
});
```

Comment: Suggest `$('iframe').on('load', function(){some code here...});` At some point in the history of jQuery, $element.load() stopped working like this.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone haha true. I updated my answer from 4 years ago. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Another way to bind to the load event of an iframe is to attach a load listener to the iframe before adding a src tag to the iframe.

Here's a simple example. This will also work with iframes that you don't control.

http://jsfiddle.net/V42ts/

```
// First add the listener.
$("#frame").load(function(){
    alert("loaded!");
});

// Then add the src
$("#frame").attr({
    src:"https://apple.com"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this from Elijah Manor's website which works very well

```js
function iFrameLoaded(id, src) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        iframe = $("<iframe class='hiddenFrame'></iframe>").attr({
            "id": id,
            "src": src
        });

    iframe.load(deferred.resolve);
    iframe.appendTo("body");

    deferred.done(function() {
        console.log("iframe loaded: " + id);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

$.when(iFrameLoaded("jQuery", "http://jquery.com"), iFrameLoaded("appendTo", "http://appendto.com")).then(function() {
    console.log("Both iframes loaded");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```