# Adding `click` event to child of `iframe` of `iframe` - not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to add a click event to one of the element which is nested inside of a `iframe` of `iframe`.

this is a iframe `.ssueContentIframe` under this, there is another `iframe` added as `#SmartReportTabContent1` so inside of the second iframe element, I am trying to add a click event like this:

Basically, I don't know when both of `iframe` will be loaded and all elements will available, for future I am adding:

```
$('.ssueContentIframe').contents().find( '#SmartReportTabContent1' ).find('.ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons.ui-grid-icon-ok.ui-grid-row-selected').on('click', function(){
             alert('Hi');
         });
```

But not working. what is the correct way to wait until both of `iframe` exist and add the click event to one of the element here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "contents" on the second iframe as well. to wait for it to load, you can use the "ready" event on the second iframe.

eg:

```
$("#SmartReportTabContent1").find("iframe").ready(function (){
    // do something once the iframe is loaded
});
```

**Update**

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436881/making-script-wait-until-iframe-has-loaded-before-running) question

Comment: can i use this inside of `onDocumentReady` - ? first iframe class name is `ssueContentIframe`, inside i am getting second iframe as `#SmartReportTabContent1`

Comment: so just use SmartReportTabContent1 as your iframe container

Comment: I tried like this: `$(document).ready(function(){

   $( '#SmartReportTabContent1' ).ready(function(){

       console.log('i am ready' );
   });
    
});` But on ready function itself i am getting consoled. ( at the time here is no iframe at all )

Comment: `ready` pseudo jq event is for `document` only, not any other DOM element

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436881/making-script-wait-until-iframe-has-loaded-before-running

Answer (score 0):

Well I edit this, first do a load of the first iframe and check it loaded well, then do the function on click on the element.

```
$(function(){
    $('#foo1').load(function(){
        alert("Loaded");
            $('#foo1').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#test').on('click', function(event) {
                alert("Working");
            });
    });
});
```

I tested it on my computer and worked perfectly, remember addind the library, if you don't add a library it won't work.

Just change the ID i used to your IDs.

Comment: I tried, but not working. may be I am wrong here. one thing is, after loading `ssueContentIframe` I am clicking on a link. that link loads the another iframe here. in side of the new one, I am trying to add the event

Comment: further more info is, content loading through `angular`- `ng-view` -