# Display div in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I can't seem to get an iframe to display a specific element. What am I doing wrong? From a StackOverflow example I'm using the following method:

Note: the iframe is embedded in a phpbb forum and references a page from within the same forum.

```
<div class="tab-content">
<form id="ucp" method="post" action="">
<div class="tab-pane">
<fieldset class="framed-ucp">
<legend>Manage notifications</legend>
<p>Here you may view all past notifications.</p>    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-left">
<li><a href="./ucp.php?i=ucp_notifications&amp;mode=notification_list&amp;mark=all&amp;token=cecbf308" class="mark" data-original-title="" title="">Mark all notifications read</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<iframe id="notify" src="example.com" seamless="seamless" width="1100" height="600">
</iframe>

document.getElementById('notify').contentWindow.document.getElementById('tab-pane')
```

Comment: Is the `protocol://domain:port` in the iframe the same as the parent page?

Comment: doh, thanks for bringing this up, i edited my original post to reflect the answer to your question - the iframe is pulling a page from within the same phobb forum, i.e. it's not pulling from an external website.

Comment: `tab-pane` is a class not an ID. Also make sure iframe has loaded before looking for elements inside it

Comment: if i change the script to: "document.getElementById('notify').contentWindow.document.getElementByClassName('tab-content')" it still doesn't work.... how would i ensure the iframe loads first? i tried these examples and no love:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436881/making-script-wait-until-iframe-has-loaded-before-running

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either:   <script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('iframe').load(function() { 

document.getElementById('notify').contentWindow.document.getElementByClassName('tab-content')

</script>

Comment: @aeneas1 Your iframe is going to "example.com" which will be "http://example.com:80" or "http://www.example.com:80".  If your page does not match that, such as if the page is on https, then that is going to *not* be considered the same domain and you will not be able to access the iframe contents with javascript.  It must be the same protocol domain and port.